# Internet stopped working on Guest OS on Hyper-V

Tags: windows-8.1, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I have Windows 8.1 machine on which I have installed Windows 2012 as guest OS using Hyper-V.

Internet was working fine on Guest OS until I made it a domain controller and now internet doesn't work. Every setting remains the same.

Firewall is OFF in both guest and host.

What could be the reason of this problem?

**EDIT**

More information about setup.

1. I am using Network Adapter in Hyper-V and not Legacy Network Adapter. Its name is WLAN.
2. Its type is Internal Network in Virtual Switch Manager.
3. Internet is shared in my WiFi as I can see name WLAN in Sharing settings of network adapter in Host OS.
4. On guest OS, the IP assigned is 192.168.137.131 and gateway is 192.168.137.1
5. On guest OS it shows a yellow icon on network icon that internet is not connected.
6. I changed Network Adapter to Legacy Network Adapter and now yellow icon is gone and it shows Internet Access in guest OS but still internet is not working and I am unable to open any site in IE.
7. IE settings are default.

Comment: I'm assuming the DC is also a DNS server. Have you set the DNS Forwarder? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754941.aspx  You can test if it's DNS by pinging an ip, such as 8.8.8.8

Comment: I pinged 8.8.8.8 from guest OS and the request timed out. So that means I need to set DNS forwarder on Guest OS?

Comment: Wouldn't seem to be a DNS issue if you're not able to ping an IP.  Perhaps more information on the network setup would help?

Comment: I have edited my post and added more information.

Comment: Now that you've changed to a Legacy Adapter and the yellow icon is gone from the network Tray icon, can you ping IPs? Either 8.8.8.8 again or your gateway?

Comment: No I cannot ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: I'm more familiar with vSphere, but in Hyper-V would you need to be set to "External" in Virtual Switch Manager?

Comment: Yes External is another option which will make a Bridge connection between guest and host but I remember I faced some other problem when used it.

Comment: I removed Legacy Network Adapter, added Network Adapter again (not legacy), then removed WLAN share from WiFi and added it again. Then restarted guest OS and now internet is working.

Answer (score 0):

I removed Legacy Network Adapter, added Network Adapter again (not legacy), then removed WLAN share from WiFi and added it again. Then restarted guest OS and now internet is working.